# Eclipse Kepler Code completion not working

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, code-completion, eclipse-kepler

I am working on an enum which contains commands for dealing with pop3 therefore I would like to store the procedure which will be performed at each command in the enum. This is what i builded:

Now my Eclipse codecompletion is not working when I try to edit 
one of the

```
 @Override
        public void doWork(Socket clientSocket, DataOutputStream outToServer, BufferedReader inFromServer, EmailAccount emailAccount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
```

Methods. I already enabled all proposaltypes in preferences -> Java -> Editor -> COntent Assist -> Advanced

Do you have any suggestions?

```
public enum CodecompletionTest {
CONST1("FOO", new Event() {

    @Override
    public void doWork(int foo, String bar) {
        // no codecompletion in here
    }

});

private CodecompletionTest(String fo, Event bar) {
    // do smth with fo and bar
}

private interface Event {
    /**
     * Verarbeitung spezifisch ausführen
     * 
     */
    public abstract void doWork(int foo, String bar);
}
}
```

Comment: For claryfication: Auto completion doesn't work if you do something inside the bodies of your `doWork()` methods? Does it work everywehere else?

Comment: yes its working in every other method or for example the enum´s constructor. And yes your claryfication is right.

Comment: Recrated a similar situation. Doesn't work for me either. I don't even get autocompletion for the creation of the annonymous inner class. I call bug on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this has already been marked as a bug in bugzilla:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395604

Answer (score 13):

Checking the Java Proposals checkbox in 
`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced` should resolve this problem.

Comment: Solved my problem and I would mark it as a solution.

Comment: Sry but I can´t confirm this. Donwloaded latest eclipse (64-bit / Eclipse Standard 4.3.2) und checked Java Proposals (in both grids). But code-completion still does not work. For a better Overview of the Problem I updated/shortened the example code.

Comment: and click restore default if you don't know select which option

Comment: @meowmeo Your suggestion is what worked for me.  theEug was very close, but with all the options, his resolution failed until your comment.  I'm upvoting his answer.  But I hope he will elaborate on what needs to be changed.  In my case is was the `Java Proposals` in the first Window that was missing the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

on ubuntu studio the ctrl-space was assigned at the operating system level to change the keyboard input method. I had to change the Next Input Method in Settings Manager–>Keyboard Input Methods–>Next Input Method field.

I changed it from ctrl-space to ctrl-alt-shift-space.